# How to I make an API request in Python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, cloud

I am trying to make an API request to my online web site scraper at [CloudScrape](http://cloudscrape.com), the [documentation](https://app.cloudscrape.com/#/api/sections/runs/executeWithInputSync) shows the following example.

> POST /api/runs/{runId}/execute/inputs/wait HTTP/1.1
>
> X-CloudScrape-Access: ga09usdm8osdf8n9sodf
> X-CloudScrape-Account: 87750c5f-7423-4438-b3f1-7b8b86990621
> Accept: application/json
> Accept-Encoding: gzip
> Content-Type: application/json
> Host: app.cloudscrape.com
> User-Agent: YourApp/1.0
> >
> >     {
> >         "my_input_field": "My input value",
> >         "my_other_input_field": 234
> >     }

I am trying to post the following parameters;

> body, runId

So far, I have tried

```
import requests
import json

client = requests.session()

runID = '86df246f-8f77-47b9-9655-be61e3851839'
inputQuery = {"query": "1080p category:movies user:z0n321 imdb:3659388"}
data = {'body':inputQuery, 'runId':'86df246f-8f77-47b9-9655-be61e3851839'}
headers = {'X-CloudScrape-Access':'a41c493c2a31d068f1a06333311e52f7', 'X-CloudScrape-Account':'87750c5f-7423-4438-b3f1-7b8b86990621', 'Accept':'application/json', 'Content-Type':'application/json'}

response = client.post('https://app.cloudscrape.com/api/runs/{%s}/execute/inputs/wait' % runID, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)

results = json.loads(response.content)
print results
```

I get this response `{u'code': 404, u'error': True}`

My scraper runs fine when I run it manually through their website. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You're getting a 404. Try this: `'https://app.cloudscrape.com/api/runs/{}/execute/inputs/wait'.format(runID)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the braces around the interpolated parameter.

```
...api/runs/%s/execute...
```

Comment: oops, silly me. Now I'm getting `{u'headers': [u'query', u'title', u'link', u'url', u'error'], u'rows': [[None, None, None, None, u'No value found for input field:query']]}`

Comment: Well, I don't know anything about that api and you can't access their docs without signing up for an account, but it doesn't look like you're passing the params correctly. The docs snippet you quote doesn't mention body, and you're already passing runid in the URL. Maybe try passing inputQuery directly as the data?

Comment: I think I need to do `inputQuery = json.dumps(inputQuery)` before passing it in to `'body'`. I'll figure it out, thanks for your help.

Comment: No it didn't work, all it says in the docs is that the parameter's name (for your input) is `body` and that the data type is `RunInputs` which should be structured as JSON, it is in the example above where it says `my_input_field`.

Comment: No, that means it's the body of the POST. You don't want the outer data dict at all.

Comment: Yes you were right, I needed to pass my input in directly as data. Thanks again. @Daniel Roseman

Answer (score 3):

You're not formatting it right. Do this:

```
'https://app.cloudscrape.com/api/runs/{}/execute/inputs/wait'.format(runID)
```